# How to update Knockout using PHP window data with Ajax? - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajax, coupon

I have the following code which is working fine.
I want to update coupon Name, Description and Amount based on a coupon code name change.

This is my php file

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class CheckoutCouponDescriptionProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $couponDescription;
    protected $couponName;

    public function __construct(
        \CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Coupon $couponDescription,
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon $couponName
    ){
        $this->couponDescription = $couponDescription;
        $this->couponName = $couponName;
    }
    public function getConfig()
    {

        $config = [];
        $config['couponCouponName'] = $this->couponName->getCouponCode();
        $config['couponDiscountAmount'] = $this->couponDescription->getDiscountAmount();
        $config['couponDiscountDescription'] = $this->couponDescription->getDiscountDescription();

        return $config;
    }
}
```

and this is my discount.js file

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_SalesRule/js/action/set-coupon-code',
        'Magento_SalesRule/js/action/cancel-coupon'
    ],
    function ($, ko, Component, quote, setCouponCodeAction, cancelCouponAction) {
        'use strict';

        var totals = quote.getTotals(),
            couponCode = ko.observable(null),
            isApplied,
            couponCouponName = ko.observable(null),
            couponDiscountAmount = ko.observable(null),
            couponDiscountDescription = ko.observable(null);

        if (totals()) {
            couponCode(totals()['coupon_code']);
        }

        isApplied = ko.observable(couponCode() != null);

        return Component.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                this.couponCouponName(window.checkoutConfig.couponCouponName);
                this.couponDiscountAmount(window.checkoutConfig.couponDiscountAmount);
                this.couponDiscountDescription(window.checkoutConfig.couponDiscountDescription);
                },

            defaults: {
                template: 'Magento_SalesRule/payment/discount'
            },
            couponCode: couponCode,
            couponCouponName: couponCouponName,
            couponDiscountAmount: couponDiscountAmount,
            couponDiscountDescription: couponDiscountDescription,


            /**
             * Applied flag
             */
            isApplied: isApplied,

            /**
             * Coupon code application procedure
             */
            apply: function() {
                if (this.validate()) {
                    setCouponCodeAction(couponCode(), isApplied);
                    console.log(couponCouponName());

                }
            },

            /**
             * Cancel using coupon
             */
            cancel: function() {
                if (this.validate()) {
                    couponCode('');
                    cancelCouponAction(isApplied);
                    console.log(couponDiscountDescription());
                }
            },

            /**
             * Coupon form validation
             *
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            validate: function () {
                var form = '#discount-form';

                return $(form).validation() && $(form).validation('isValid');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

edited few lines in .js file so it's more correct